# Convert data XML Node into DataTable

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, wcf

I have SharePoint list data and I got that data from My SharePoint List in XML Node format
as follows

```
XmlNode nodeListItems = listService.GetListItems(listName, "", ndQuery, null, rowLimit, null, "");
```

Please help me how to convert this data into dataTable or dataSet

Answer (score 0):

If `GetListItems` returns `SPListItemCollection` than you can use [`SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.getdatatable.aspx) method